# Get surrounding element of javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have code that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() { 
      var s = document.createElement('script'); 
      s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'localhost/chat/logo.js'); 
      var t = document.getElementById('craftysyntax'); 
      t.appendChild(s, t); 
    })(); 
  </script>
<div>
```

I want the file that was loaded by async' to be able to do something like this (note: this is not working js code, but it is what I want to do)

```
parent.appendChild(abc);
```

which will add the child element `abc` in the parent `div`.

So, is there any way the script can reference its parent container?

Edit:
Why do I want to do this?
My website (an online store) uses a chat program with a link in the navigation bar that changes based on whether there is an operator logged in to the chat program. I am trying to convert the program to use an asynchronous loader, but the external js can not use `document.write` if it has been loaded asynchronously. I am trying to convert all of the `document.write` calls in the script to use the dom instead.

Comment: why would you want the loaded file to do that?

Comment: Yes, this really doesn't make much sense, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I added the specific circumstances to the question...

Comment: It looks like you just want to append the script to the DOM and have it execute.  Is there a particular reason why it needs to be at that exact place in the DOM?

Comment: @digitalbath the script outputs an image based on whether there is a customer service rep logged in to the operator console. the imae is supposed to go in a particular place on the page.

Comment: Far simpler to just replace the image on the server and have the client upload the new image from time to time (say each minute). Adding a script element to add an image element just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RobG, it is not just an image, it also gets us analytics data. In truth, the other javascript file is actually a php file (the server runs .js through php) which logs information about the user's browser and location, (etc).

Comment: I have been trying to post the answer that I worked out over the last hour, but StackOverflow keeps saying "New users can't answer their own question for 8 hours. Please use comments, or edit your question instead." so I will try posting it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into an old friend from school and we discussed this and figured out this solution.

I will have the inline script create its own div named based on the current time (or something like that).
Then I can pass the id of the div to the other script in the query string.
(I already have the `getQueryString` function)

Inline

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var randval = "helpbox" + Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
  document.write('<div id="' + randval + '"></div>');
  (function() { 
     var csc = document.createElement('script'); 
     csc.type = 'text/javascript'; 
     csc.src = 'a1.js?divid=' + randval; 
     var s = document.getElementById('help'); 
     s.appendChild(csc, s); 
  })();
```

External

```
var my_div = document.getElementById(getQuerystring('divid'));
```

Answer (score 3):

When your code is immediately executed like that, the last `script` element will be the current one (because of synchronous downloading and executing).

So you can get a reference to all `script` elements, and then get the last one using the `length` property minus one.

Then you can access its parent node with `parentNode` property.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var allScripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        thisScriptParent = allScripts[scripts.length - 1].parentNode;
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pC52c/).

Also, there is no need to use a ternary to check for `https`. Just use protocol-less (`//localhost/chat/logo.js`) and it will resolve to the parent site's protocol.

Comment: But the point of loading the script that way is that it NOT loaded synchronously: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncTracking.html

Comment: @yakatz You'd have to place this code alongside where you create the `script` element.

Comment: @yakatz It does work, just perhaps not for your specific circumstance. I'll have a look at your example when it goes up.

Comment: http://www.ymkatz.net/examples/async_js/ . There are two divs, `help` and `abc`. The popup should say `help`, but says `abc`

Comment: @yakatz I'm using Chrome 11 and error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`.

Comment: I fixed it... (I don't like this minimum comment length). It was a sloppy copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @yakatz Yeah, it won't work like that, that's why my second comment says *You'd have to place this code alongside where you create the script element.*.

Comment: I suppose I could pass the element id in the URL and do getElementById in the external script.

Comment: @yakatz That is assuming your parent `div` *has* an `id`.

Comment: I think I will have the inline script create its own `div` named based on the current time (or something like that). That will solve the whole problem. I will pass its name to the other script in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reliably get the script tag that the code is running from.

I'm not sure why your logo.js script doesn't just directly get the element by its id ("craftysyntax"), but if you are looking for a more general solution (where you could, say, add multiple such elements/scripts to the document in rapid succession, without having them mess each other up), you could do something like this:

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() { 
      var s = document.createElement('script'); 
      s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'localhost/chat/logo.js'); 
      var t = document.getElementById('craftysyntax'); 
      if (window.global_chatElems == null)
        global_chatElems = [];
      global_chatElems.push(t);
      t.appendChild(s); 
    })(); 
  </script>
<div>
```

then in your logo.js script:

```
if (window.globalChatElems) {
  for (var i=0; i<globalChatElems.length; i++)
    processChatElem(globalChatElems[i]);
  window.globalChatElems = null;
  }
```

Of course, if you are only allowing one of these elements per page, everything is much simpler....no need to make the global be an array, it can just be a single variable.